# Android Espresso: Intent matchers and androidx PreferenceFragments

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I've recently migrated my preference implementation to use `androidx.preference`s. This caused one of my instrumentation tests to fail and I haven't found a reasonable workaround to make it pass.

In the test I have a dialog that displays an error if some condition in the app preferences is met. In this test a specific preference is disabled. The user can click on the error to open the specific preference and that way go in and change it. The problem is I can't figure out how to assert that the correct PreferenceFragment is displayed.

The tests that fails looks like this:

```
@Test
fun whenWorklistNotEnabled_shouldDisplayWorklistNotEnabledMessage() {
    val manager = PreferenceManagerImpl(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
    whenever(preferenceManagerSpy.worklistEnabled).thenReturn(false)
    whenever(preferenceManagerSpy.openDicomSettings()).thenAnswer { manager.openWorklistSettings() }

    launchWorklistDialog()

    onView(withErrorMessageView(R.id.dialog_worklist_errorview))
        .check(
            matches(
                allOf(
                    isDisplayed(),
                    withPrimaryErrorText(R.string.global_worklist_disabled_error),
                    withSecondaryErrorText(R.string.dialog_worklist_worklist_disabled_error_secondary_text)
                )
            )
        )
        .perform(ErrorMessageViewActions.actionOnSecondaryTextContainer(click()))

    intended(
        allOf<Intent>(
            IntentMatchers.hasComponent(
                ComponentName(
                    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
                    SettingsActivity::class.java
                )
            ),
            IntentMatchers.hasExtra(
                PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT,
                WorklistFragment::class.java
            )
        )
    )
}
```

But how can you rewrite it to match a specific PreferenceFragment when you no longer use a PreferenceActivity implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after looking at the stacktrace of the failing test:

```
Recorded intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.example/.preferences.SettingsActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.example]], extras:[Bundle[{EXTRA_SHOW_DICOM_FRAGMENT=class com.example.preferences.WorklistFragment}]])
```

The solution:

```
intended(
    allOf<Intent>(
        IntentMatchers.hasComponent(
            ComponentName(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
                SettingsActivity::class.java
            )
        ),
        IntentMatchers.hasExtra(
            EXTRA_SHOW_WORKLIST_FRAGMENT,
            WorklistFragment::class.java
        )
    )
)
```